# Omitting a parameter from @RequiredArgsConstructor that is set through @Value

Tags: java, spring-boot, lombok

Suppose there's a class in a Spring Boot project:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
public class A {

    @Value("${a.category:RANDOM}")
    private final String CATEGORY;

    private final String name;
    private final String mail;
}
```

You can see that there are 3 fields annotated with final, thus the `@RequiredArgsConstructor` will, by default, create a constructor with each of these parameters.

However, there's one field - `CATEGORY` - that is set using `@Value` annotation. Because of that, I'd like this field to be omitted while constructing an instance of this class.

Does Lombok support some elegant solution to this problem? Note that I don't want to change access modifiers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is currently [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23761242/java-lombok-omitting-one-field-in-allargsconstructor), as you can check in [the documentation](https://projectlombok.org/features/constructor).

Your issue is different: you should not perform field injection on a final field. A final field should be immutable after construction; field injection changes it after construction. While it is *possible* to change a final field, this changes the invariants of your Java program and [should be considered an sloppy hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42186358/field-injection-with-final-field-in-guice).

If you want to use field injection, the following class is completely fine:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
public class A {

    @Value("${a.category:RANDOM}")
    private String CATEGORY;

    private final String name;
    private final String mail;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Why is that?

Comment: @IceMajor Because a final field should be immutable after construction. Field injection happens after the object is already instantiated. See point 4 here: https://www.baeldung.com/java-spring-field-injection-cons

Comment: Oh, yes. You are right, I'll autowire `@Value` annotation in my constructor and will omit using Lombok for this class ;)